# C++ Is there a guarantee of constancy of untouched float values?

Tags: c++, testing

I would like to know if I can assume that the value of a float will not change if I just pass it around functions, without any further calculations. I would like to write some tests for that kind of functions using hardcoded values.

Example :

```
float identity(float f) { return f; }
```

Can I write the following test :

```
TEST() {
    EXPECT(identity(1.8f) == 1.8f);
}
```

Comment: All copies, no references around. Looks all safe.

Comment: Yes, except that this can fail, because the representation of 15.8 as a `float` may not be the same as its representation as a literal, which is a `double`.

Comment: I believe you're asking this due to the roundoff errors fuss

Comment: [Just as I thought](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/259e520a2aac3fa2). Look at those warnings!

Comment: Ok I get that but I was planning to use hardcoded const arrays of floats anyway, without comparisons with litterals. I'll change to double so that it's more clear.

Comment: @ElefEnt Alternatively, if you don't need that many bits, you can use float literals (`15.8f`);

Comment: In practice, using x87, `x+y==identity(x+y)` can return false with gcc unless you pass some very specific flags.

Comment: We can't say anything about what `indentity` (note the stray `n`) will do since you only showed the code for `identity`, a different function.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant in your example you didn't specify the f suffix, and in that case there are rounding issues indeed. 
The example in the question is perfectly fine though.
reference: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Comment: @dau_sama perhaps look at the **original question** before trying to educate me about syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the C++ standard doesn't make guarantees if it's known that the guarantee will lead to sub-optimal code for some processor architecture.

The legacy x86 floating point processing uses 80-bit registers for calculations. The mere act of moving a value from one of those registers into 64 bits of memory causes rounding to occur.

Answer (score 1):

If you're [not performing any lossy operation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and just passing the floating point data around it should be safe to assume (assuming there are no interferences or optimization bugs) that the values will remain the same. Just make sure you're not comparing floating point values with literal values interpreted as double (`EXPECT(indentity(1.8f)  == 1.8);`) or vice-versa.

```
/paranoid_level on
```

However you should always check your target architecture behavior with floating point numbers, especially with respect to the [IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point): on a system which allows IEEE 754 exceptions under specific circumstances (e.g. `-ftz` flags often used in GPUs) you might end up having results inconsistent with your expectations (possibly when combining smart compiler optimizations) since results might be handled internally in a different manner. An example is an architecture which applies to **any** floating point operation a *denormals-are-zero* (`-daz`) policy.

Answer (score 0):

That is perfectly fine and the value will be identical.

As pointed out in the comments, if you were to write:

```
TEST() {
    EXPECT(indentity(1.8)  == 1.8f);
    EXPECT(indentity(1.8l) == 1.8f);
}
```

you could end up having problems, due to implicit conversions from int/double.
however if you compare floats with floats, you're perfectly safe.

[reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)